# PHP remembers POST value after refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I've got a problem with a html form. Php seems to remember my POST value after refreshing my page. It has to do with a login form that I uses.

I'm using cookies to let php communicate with javascript, telling javascript if the user is logged in or not.

Php code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = MD5($_POST['password']);

    echo '<script>console.log("' . $username . '", "username"); </script>';
    echo '<script>console.log("' . $password . '" , "password"); </script>';


    /* against sql injections */
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $query = "SELECT user_id FROM User WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if ($row[user_id]){
        $cookie_name = "login";
        $cookie_value = "1";
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    } else{
        echo '<script> alert("Incorrect username and password combination");</script>';
    }
}

?>
```

The form:

```
<form method="POST" id="loginForm">
    <b>Login</b>
    <table style="margin-top: 10px">
        <tr><td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required="required"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password: </td><td><input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" required="required"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" style="margin-top: 5px"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Because I love javascript, I'm using a ajax call to communicate with php and the server database.

Javascript code:

```
function openPage(page) {
    var content;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/php/' + page + '.php',
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById('contentMiddle').innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The problem is whenever I try to refresh the page, my php code will always run and $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] will always have the POST value from before refreshing the page.

I always make sure I remove the cookie before refreshing the page.

Any idea?

Comment: Call it a blessing in disguise. Using MD5 is no longer considered safe to use, so is the MySQL API you're using also. Use `password_hash()` and prepared statements.

Comment: I would use the /Post/Redirect/Get method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: you sure you're not resending post values on refresh?

Comment: Instead of actually refreshing the page, try clicking into the address bar and hitting Enter. This will reload the page without re-submitting the form.

Comment: Are the cookies even working? You cannot set cookies in php after you have sent output to the browser.

Comment: Thx Fred! I will use password_hash(). But that doesnt solve the problem.

Im pretty sure im not resending POST values on refresh and cookies are working correctly.

Comment: "setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output."

Comment: I will solve the cookie issue later. The cookie is not the problem. I removed it and replaced it with a echo... After refreshing the POST is still there...

Comment: I solved the problem with some changes in the code and using GET instead of POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've most likely already submitted the page and by hitting refresh the browser is attempting to send the POST data along with the refresh.

Since you're using Ajax to process your form you can/should remove `type="submit"` from the login button since there's no need for it. Instead you can have Login.

Then update your Ajax to run when the button is clicked. You can also use jQuery to get your elements by ID, for example:

```
$("#btn_login").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/php/' + page + '.php',
        success: function (data) {
            //document.getElementById('contentMiddle').innerHTML = data;
            $("#contentMiddle").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

To address the comment by @charlietfl, handling an Enter press to submit the form you'd use something like this.

```
document.onkeydown = function(){
    if(window.event.keyCode=='13'){
        $("#loginForm").submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: why is there no need for a `submit` button, many users including myself far prefer using keyboard to submit. That's also why it's better to bind ajax to submit event of form not a button click

Comment: Good point on Enter submitting the form, but that's easily solved without submit. Another reason for using Ajax is the fact that there's no need to refresh the whole page, which AFAIK is always going to happen when an input is type="submit", hence his problem. I also should have mentioned that the <input> be substituted with <button type="button" id="login">Login</button> and not as an <input> without type="submit".

Comment: no, you capture the submit event of form and preventDefault and do ajax inside submit handler. Need `type=submit` to allow `Enter`. No need keypress or keydown handlers that way. In fact your key handelr would bypass ajax

Comment: preventDefault when you can just change the HTML? Seems silly.

Comment: You have to preventDefault. Same with your button clcik. You aren't preventing the browser from also submitting the form

Comment: <button type="button"> will not submit the form, that's my whole point.